# how to multiply file to upload using icon button

Tags: jquery

I start to write script that allow users to click on icon and to choose image to upload.
I would like to allow user to upload multiply files. how can i do that (using the icon button in order to open the browser dialog)

this is what i done:

jsfiddle.net/wsurube2/

Comment: maybe talk about where you are experiencing problems - identify the problematic area and tailor your question to that.

Answer (score 0):

The HTMLInputElement with type="file" has a .multiple property that indicates if an input can have more than one value. You can then access the files using the element.files collection by index.

input.files[index]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/multiple

HTML: add multiple as an attribute.

```
<input type='file' name='file[]' class=' form-control file-field hide' max_files_upload='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" style="display: none" multiple/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/wsurube2/1/

```
// validation for images
    $(function() {
        $('input.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
            alert(this.files.length);
            var filename = $(this).val();
            if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(filename)) {
                this.value = '';
                $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("<span class='valid_msg'>Images only!</span>");
            }
            else
                $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("IMAGE: " + filename + " <button class='clear_file btn btn-default btn-xs'>REMOVE</button>");
      });
    });
```

Comment: You will need to test for compatibility as the multiple attribute is an HTML5 attribute. (IE10+)

Comment: Sean Wessell (-it's doesn't tag you...:/ ). I checked your code - the second file i choose replace the first one i attached. i need that both of the to be displayed...so i can upload them both...

Comment: @roi See this updated fiddle to get an idea of what you need to do. You need to loop through each file in the .files collection. http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/wsurube2/2/

Comment: Just preceded your name with @.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge with jquery. that's why I need your help. I checked the second code you publish -this is what i need, but: 1. the remove button delete all the files and not just the one i click on. 2. will  your code upload 2 files?

Comment: I tried to add @ before you nickname. doesn't work...:/

Comment: files is a read only list. so even though you would be able to remove the input filename from your span by correcting the jQuery remove you will not be able to remove the file from the .files collection. So when you went to post to the server you would send all of the files. I'm not aware of a workaround for this.